# Не вызывается onCreate()

Tags: java, android, activity

Начал изучать [android](/questions/tagged/android) Такая проблема, не вызывается метод `onCreate()`. Создал тестовую активность `TestActivity`

```
package com.likha.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        Log.d("MyTag", "In TestActivity, onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
    }
}
```

Вызываю активность из фрагмента `CrimeFragment` в обработчике касания `onClick()`

**Лишнее удалено из листинга**

```
package com.likha.criminalintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by likha on 04.07.2017.
 */

public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {

   /..../
    private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        /....../

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MyTag", "In CrimeListFragment, onClick");
            /*Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(),
                    mCrime.getId());*/
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), TestActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

**Манифест файл:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.likha.criminalintent">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".CrimePagerActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Все вызовы методов прологированы, метод не вызывается. Активность по обработчику касания открывается, в логах запись о вызове `onClick()` появляется, но активность открывается просто пустой, там ничего нет, хотя должен быть текст.

**В окне ошибок вот это:**

```
07-06 10:25:26.685 17037-17037/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
07-06 10:25:26.723 17037-17037/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-06 10:25:26.723 17037-17037/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-06 10:25:26.737 1621-1670/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '45fed53 com.likha.criminalintent/com.likha.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-06 10:25:26.761 17049-17054/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
07-06 10:25:28.880 17073-17073/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
07-06 10:25:28.929 17073-17073/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-06 10:25:28.929 17073-17073/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-06 10:25:30.303 17120-17120/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
07-06 10:25:30.358 17120-17120/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-06 10:25:30.358 17120-17120/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-06 10:25:32.980 17164-17164/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
07-06 10:25:33.023 2032-2595/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
07-06 10:25:33.023 2032-2595/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
07-06 10:25:33.044 2453-11151/com.google.android.gms E/Drive.UninstallOperation: Package still installed com.likha.criminalintent
07-06 10:25:33.068 17164-17164/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-06 10:25:33.068 17164-17164/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-06 10:25:33.152 2032-2595/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
07-06 10:25:33.152 2032-2595/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
07-06 10:25:33.329 17201-17201/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
07-06 10:25:33.384 17201-17201/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-06 10:25:33.384 17201-17201/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-06 10:25:33.451 1326-1326/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1326: eglCreateSyncKHR(1669): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-06 10:25:33.526 1732-1732/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.likha.criminalintent-2/base.apk
07-06 10:25:33.526 1732-1732/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.likha.criminalintent-2/base.apk
07-06 10:25:33.526 1732-1732/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.likha.criminalintent-2/base.apk
07-06 10:25:33.806 1326-3157/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

                                                 [ 07-06 10:25:33.809 17244:17244 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaebade80, tid 17244
```

Ошибка, наверное, мелкая, но я не понимаю где. Спасибо.

Comment: R.layout.test прикрепите тоже

Comment: Может у вас просто уровень отображения логов установлен на Error в AndroidMonitor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Метод:

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

вызывается у активити, для которых атрибут `persistableMode` установлен в `persistAcrossReboots`.

Используйте *обычный* метод `onCreate(...)`:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: Вот оно где. Огромное спасибо за такую быструю помощь.